# Call the function using pointer-to-pointer to function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Pointers declaration:

```cpp
void (**Func1Ptr)() = {NULL};//pointer-to-pointer to function
void (*Func2Ptr)() = {NULL};//pointer to function
```

Two functions:

```cpp
void FuncA()
{
}

void FuncB()
{
}
```

Now `Func2Ptr` points to `FuncA` address:

```cpp
Func2Ptr = FuncA;
```

And now `Func1Ptr` points to pointer to `FuncA` address:

```cpp
Func1Ptr = &Func2Ptr;
```

And there is a question - how to call function using `Func1Ptr`?

Comment: do you know how to call the function using pointer to function? Do you know how to dereference a pointer?

Comment: Unrelated: Don't write code like this.

Comment: @user12002570 -- obscure fact: `(*******Func1Ptr)()` also works. As does `& & & & & FuncA`. Pointers-to-functions are weird.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was aware of the former `(*******FuncPtr)()` but not the latter `& & & & FuncA` I think. Can you give an example of how/where the latter syntax you mentioned in [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/96YzG9Ev3) will work? I don't think `auto Func2Ptr = & & & FuncA)` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to call function using `Func1Ptr`?

There are two ways/syntax for calling using `Func1Ptr` is as shown below:

```
//dereference Func1Ptr and then dereference the result and then use the call operator ()
(**Func1Ptr)();  
(*Func1Ptr)(); //another way of calling
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/96YzG9Ev3)

Comment: @Ig_M  For example, refer to [How come pointer to a function be called without dereferencing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944479/how-come-pointer-to-a-function-be-called-without-dereferencing) and [Calling a function through a function pointer - dereference the pointer or not? What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472443/calling-a-function-through-a-function-pointer-dereference-the-pointer-or-not). In fact you could've written `(********Func1Ptr)(); ` and that would work too. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r6Y4fP1G7)

Comment: @Ig_M In fact you could've written `(********Func1Ptr)(); ` and that would work too. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r6Y4fP1G7)